# libvlc after 12 instances hardware accelerator failed to decode picture error

Tags: c++, libvlc, hardware-acceleration

I am using libvlc 3.0.11 sdk. I have multiple instances of vlc player in my program developed in Qt platform. I am using `libvlc_media_new_callbacks` API to read data from custom buffer. There isn't any problem until 12 instance of players but when I increase the number of instances, libVLC gives that error

> hardware accelerator failed to decode picture

with red text color.
If I open multiple instances of my own program, I can create 12 instances for each program and works fine. According from this, I think this is not hardware-capacity related problem. I have tried different hardware accelereation options but I could'nt make it work. I need help

Comment: share a repro please